# Started making a game and all worked fine but then the move function stopped working

Tags: python, pygame

I cant find what i changed so that my move function doesnt work anymore, it worked perfectly before. I dont get any errors it just doesnt move at all.
Sorry if the code is really sloppy.
Most indentation errors are probably because i formatted it wrong(its my first time using stackoverflow).

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

work = True
b_y = 425
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
newWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("NewFile")

class player:

    def __init__(self, vel, x):
        self.x = x
        self.vel = vel

    def playerdraw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(newWindow, (255, 255, 255),  (p1.x, 425,
40,20))

    def  move(self):
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and p1.x>5:
             p1.x -=  self.vel
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and p1.x < 455:
             p1.x += self.vel  


p1 = player(2, 250)
b_x = p1.x

while work:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            work= False

    newWindow.fill((0, 0, 0))

    p1.move()
    p1.playerdraw()

    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

I need the player to move

Answer (score 1):

You've to set `key`, continuously in the main game loop:

```py
while work:

    # [...]

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

Note, you've initialized `key` at the begin of the application, but you've missed to update it. The state of the keys which is stored in the list `key` in global name space is evaluated in the method `move()` of the class `player`.
 [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list of boolean values representing the state of every key. The internal states of the keys are updated when the (key) events are evaluated. After that `pygame.key.get_pressed()` will return new and actual values.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I initially had key defined in the main loop but I moved it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to read the get_pressed key function on each loop**

```
    def  move(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed() # You need to read the get_pressed key function on each loop
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and p1.x>5:
             p1.x -=  self.vel
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and p1.x < 455:
             p1.x += self.vel
```

**Complete Code**

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

work = True
b_y = 425
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
newWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("NewFile")

class player:

    def __init__(self, vel, x):
        self.x = x
        self.vel = vel

    def playerdraw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(newWindow, (255, 255, 255),  (p1.x, 425,
40,20))

    def  move(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed() # You need to read the get_pressed key function on each loop
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and p1.x>5:
             p1.x -=  self.vel
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and p1.x < 455:
             p1.x += self.vel  


p1 = player(2, 250)
b_x = p1.x

while work:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            work= False

    newWindow.fill((0, 0, 0))

    p1.move()
    p1.playerdraw()

    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```